# TypeScript won't change error (terminal output) even when problem has been fixed in React application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm new to TypeScript and am facing this annoying problem. The terminal (or whole project) won't auto refresh as regular React apps with JS do. Usually, as I make changes and fix bugs pointed out by the linter, the development server will auto refresh and show either the compiled product or the subsequent bugs.

This is happening both in projects that are migrating from JS to TS and projects that are started with TS.

tsconfig.json for project bootstraped with create-react-app and TS

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

In one of the projects I kicked off with TS, this is how I installed things:

```
npx create-react-app my-project --template typescript
```

In another project in which I am trying to migrate, this is how I installed the necessary things:

```
npm install -D typescript
npx tsc -init 
npm install -D @types/react @types/react-dom @types/reach__router
```

Answer (score 0):

I can observe the same thing. Not a real fix but a quick workaround: Insert a space somewhere (in an empty line for example) and save the file. The error should have gone.